# Specialization of a function in different namespace

Tags: c++, templates

I am getting the following error when I try to build the code.

> src/Test.cxx:29: error: specialization of 'template T
>   com::check::one::Test::getValue(const std::string&)' in different
>   namespace ./incl/Test.hxx:30: error:   from definition of
>   'template T com::check::one::Test::getValue(const
>   std::string&)' src/Test.cxx:31: confused by earlier errors, bailing
>   out

**Header file:**

```
namespace com::check::one
{
    class Test
    {
    public:
        template<typename T>
        T getValue(const std::string& var);
    };
}
```

**Source File:**

```
using namespace com::check::one;

template<>
std::vector<std::string> Test::getValue(const std::string& var)
{
    //statements
}
```

I am using the correct namespace and included the header file as well. No issues in compile. Even I have defined other member functions of the Test Class in source file. No issues for those functions. Only there is a issue with this function which has template. The error is during build. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

`using namespace com.check.one;` is not a valid syntax. It should be:

```
using namespace com::check::one;
```

Even better, wrap definitions into namespace:

```
namespace com::check::one
{
    class Test
    {
        public:
        template<typename T>
        T getValue(const std::string& var);
    };
}

namespace com::check::one
{
    template<>
    std::vector<std::string> Test::getValue(const std::string& var)
    {
        //statements
    }
}
```

Also you should read [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Comment: Sorry its a typo here. I defined it correctly in the source code.

Answer (score 1):

I expect something like this in the cpp file:

```
namespace com {
namespace check {
namespace one {
template<>
std::vector<std::string> Test::getValue(const std::string& var)
{
//statements
}
}
}
}
```

This:

```
using namespace com.check.one;
```

is more like Java than C++. C++ - `using namespace com::check::one;`. And it's for using the namespace, not for defining things in it.